# Devise: How to create an alternate new member registration cycle?

Tags: devise, ruby-on-rails-3.2

**ENVIRONMENT**

ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [x86_64-darwin10.8.0]; Rails 3.2.6; OSX 10.6.8: devise (2.0.4)

**BACKGROUND**

We have a regular Devise member registration cycle in which:

1. a sign_up form is accompanied by substantial related information;
2. and in which successful registration (sign_up) invokes a member account page ― also with substantial related information.
3. **We also have needs for a separate registration cycle without the relatively massive information accompanying both of these views.**

**OBJECTIVE**

We would like to create **a separate registration (sign_up) cycle** in which:

1. **a minimal sign_up form** configured for hand-helds takes registration information (without the massive related information of our regular existing cycle);
2. **but which successful registration process does not log in the registrant;**
3. in which successful registration therefore, **instead, registration after registration displays a minimal confirmation page with the registration information of each of ultimately many further registrations** (never of the logged member, nor storing private information to the user agent);
4. and with this simple registration information page manually linking back to the minimal sign_up form (1) to take further registrations with what we're calling a "kiosk mode."

**QUESTION**

How would we do this with Devise?